# How to compare 2 arrays in Javascript and make one new one of trues and falses?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i have 2 arrays in Javascript and i want to compare one with the other to see if the elements of array1 exists in array2, and then make one new array with the same length of the second array but containing only trues and falses (being true the values that exists and false the ones that don't). like this :

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3]
var arr2 = [3,9,11,2,20]
```

And the new array that i want to create with the same length that 'arr2' but only with boolean values:

```
var finalArray = [true, false, false, true, false]
```

In this case only 2 true values because only '3' and '2' are in the arr1.

At the moment i am doing a map over an array but this push all values to true or false, like this:

```
var newArray = arr2.map(x => (x = false));
```

Can anyone help me? I am using Vuejs and this is for a list of checkbox being the true values the ones that are checked.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as `thisArg` of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the prototype of [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) as callback.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3],
    array2 = [3, 9, 11, 2, 20],
    finalArray = array2.map(Set.prototype.has, new Set(array1));

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [3,9,11,2,20];

var resultArray = arr2.map(value => arr1.includes(value));
```